# Travel Ticket Booking API

Tags: asp.net, api

I can find there are multiple API available to book bus tickets , flight tickets and so on like (expedia , redbus) . I just need to know where these systems are centralized and how they are doing it ? . Well it seems a rookie question unfortunately im one of them .

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0):

You're spot on, they *are* centralized. I have friends who work in companies on both sides of the table (Hipmunk, Hotwire, etc). You'll notice when you browse their listing, it's all the same information wrapped in a different UI with a couple of different promotions added on. They're all able to serve you the **same** price/data because they all have *leverage*. With this leverage, travel agencies, airlines, and hotels, are able to aggregate and vend this information to all these travel brands in an organized fashion. Unless you have the buying power of these large corporations, you essentially have to use their API.

Comment: Thanks catridgemeadow . I have a requirement from one of my client who was a reputed travelling firm proposed to me in this . If he wants online booking on Hipmunk how it is approached . Is there any role i can play in this ?

Comment: Hey Ananth, the best API for developers wanting to book flights are through sky scanner's and flight stats's API (http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/AffiliateNetwork?_ga=1.6017520.211757316.1406671083#api) &  (https://developer.flightstats.com/products); Hipmunk currently doesn't have a public API for developers. Please let me know if you have any other questions!